# extract countries data from sql using regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I got SQL for inserting countries, I just want to save some columns instead of all columns in the SQL query.

I have cleaned the data using regex but facing only one little problem. The regex doesn't match if the values are starting in the same line, I am using regex101.com for replacing

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kUW4Ug/1).

---

**My Regex**

```
(\(([0-9]),(['a-zA-Z ]*),(['a-zA-Z ]*)).*
```

**Sample data**

```
(1,'Afghanistan','AFG','004','AF','93','Kabul','AFN','Afghan afghani','؋','.af','افغانستان','Asia','Southern Asia','[{\"zoneName\":\"Asia/Kabul\",\"gmtOffset\":16200,\"gmtOffsetName\":\"UTC+04:30\",\"abbreviation\":\"AFT\",\"tzName\":\"Afghanistan Time\"}]','{\"kr\":\"아프가니스탄\",\"br\":\"Afeganistão\",\"pt\":\"Afeganistão\",\"nl\":\"Afghanistan\",\"hr\":\"Afganistan\",\"fa\":\"افغانستان\",\"de\":\"Afghanistan\",\"es\":\"Afganistán\",\"fr\":\"Afghanistan\",\"ja\":\"アフガニスタン\",\"it\":\"Afghanistan\",\"cn\":\"阿富汗\",\"tr\":\"Afganistan\"}',33.00000000,65.00000000,'','U+1F1E6 U+1F1EB','2018-07-21 07:11:03','2022-05-21 21:06:00',1,'Q889'),
(2,'Aland Islands','ALA','248','AX','+358-18','Mariehamn','EUR','Euro','€','.ax','Åland','Europe','Northern Europe','[{\"zoneName\":\"Europe/Mariehamn\",\"gmtOffset\":7200,\"gmtOffsetName\":\"UTC+02:00\",\"abbreviation\":\"EET\",\"tzName\":\"Eastern European Time\"}]','{\"kr\":\"올란드 제도\",\"br\":\"Ilhas de Aland\",\"pt\":\"Ilhas de Aland\",\"nl\":\"Ålandeilanden\",\"hr\":\"Ålandski otoci\",\"fa\":\"جزایر الند\",\"de\":\"Åland\",\"es\":\"Alandia\",\"fr\":\"Åland\",\"ja\":\"オーランド諸島\",\"it\":\"Isole Aland\",\"cn\":\"奥兰群岛\",\"tr\":\"Åland Adalari\"}',60.11666700,19.90000000,'','U+1F1E6 U+1F1FD','2018-07-21 07:11:03','2022-05-21 21:06:00',1,NULL),
(3,'Albania','ALB','008','AL','355','Tirana','ALL','Albanian lek','Lek','.al','Shqipëria','Europe','Southern Europe','[{\"zoneName\":\"Europe/Tirane\",\"gmtOffset\":3600,\"gmtOffsetName\":\"UTC+01:00\",\"abbreviation\":\"CET\",\"tzName\":\"Central European Time\"}]','{\"kr\":\"알바니아\",\"br\":\"Albânia\",\"pt\":\"Albânia\",\"nl\":\"Albanië\",\"hr\":\"Albanija\",\"fa\":\"آلبانی\",\"de\":\"Albanien\",\"es\":\"Albania\",\"fr\":\"Albanie\",\"ja\":\"アルバニア\",\"it\":\"Albania\",\"cn\":\"阿尔巴尼亚\",\"tr\":\"Arnavutluk\"}',41.00000000,20.00000000,'','U+1F1E6 U+1F1F1','2018-07-21 07:11:03','2022-05-21 21:06:00',1,'Q222'),(4,'Algeria','DZA','012','DZ','213','Algiers','DZD','Algerian dinar','دج','.dz','الجزائر','Africa','Northern Africa','[{\"zoneName\":\"Africa/Algiers\",\"gmtOffset\":3600,\"gmtOffsetName\":\"UTC+01:00\",\"abbreviation\":\"CET\",\"tzName\":\"Central European Time\"}]','{\"kr\":\"알제리\",\"br\":\"Argélia\",\"pt\":\"Argélia\",\"nl\":\"Algerije\",\"hr\":\"Alžir\",\"fa\":\"الجزایر\",\"de\":\"Algerien\",\"es\":\"Argelia\",\"fr\":\"Algérie\",\"ja\":\"アルジェリア\",\"it\":\"Algeria\",\"cn\":\"阿尔及利亚\",\"tr\":\"Cezayir\"}',28.00000000,3.00000000,'','U+1F1E9 U+1F1FF','2018-07-21 07:11:03','2022-05-21 21:06:00',1,'Q262'),(5,'American Samoa','ASM','016','AS','+1-684','Pago Pago','USD','US Dollar','$','.as','American Samoa','Oceania','Polynesia','[{\"zoneName\":\"Pacific/Pago_Pago\",\"gmtOffset\":-39600,\"gmtOffsetName\":\"UTC-11:00\",\"abbreviation\":\"SST\",\"tzName\":\"Samoa Standard Time\"}]','{\"kr\":\"아메리칸사모아\",\"br\":\"Samoa Americana\",\"pt\":\"Samoa Americana\",\"nl\":\"Amerikaans Samoa\",\"hr\":\"Američka Samoa\",\"fa\":\"ساموآی آمریکا\",\"de\":\"Amerikanisch-Samoa\",\"es\":\"Samoa Americana\",\"fr\":\"Samoa américaines\",\"ja\":\"アメリカ領サモア\",\"it\":\"Samoa Americane\",\"cn\":\"美属萨摩亚\",\"tr\":\"Amerikan Samoasi\"}',-14.33333333,-170.00000000,'','U+1F1E6 U+1F1F8','2018-07-21 07:11:03','2022-05-21 21:06:00',1,NULL),
```

**Replacement Data**

`$1, 1, NOW(), NOW()),`

**Expected Output**

```
('Afghanistan','AFG', 1, NOW(), NOW()),
('Aland Islands','ALA', 1, NOW(), NOW()),
('Albania','ALB', 1, NOW(), NOW()),
```

Comment: REGEX not needed. `CONCAT_WS(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ',', 3), 1, NOW(), NOW())`.

Comment: @Akina can you explain it more please

Comment: It is hard without the token requirement specs. Try a naive approach like  `(\([0-9]+,['a-zA-Z ]*,['a-zA-Z ]*)(,('[^']*'|[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+))*\),?` See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/u0Ea5R/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is working but some issue with other values, can you tell me how you shared demo so I can share it mine

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PrkYqG/1 here is mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern I notice in your regex attempt divides in matching two groups:

- Group 1 (replaced), which contains a parenthesis, the first digits and a comma
- Group 2 (retained), which contains any character before a comma, a quote and another group of digits,
- Group 3 (replaced), which contains the rest of the string, ending in `),` for every row, except the last one that ends with `);`

The translation of this description into regex pattern is the following:

```
(\(\d+,)(.*?(?=,'\d))(.*?(?:\)([,;])))
```

**Group 1** Regex Explanation `\(\d+,)`:

- `\(`: an open parenthesis
- `\d+`: any combination of digits
- `,`: a comma

**Group 2** Regex Explanation `(.*?(?=,'\d))`:

- `.*?`: any combination of characters (lazy - the least possible)
- `(?=,'\d)`: before a comma followed by a quote and a digit (excluded from the match)

**Group 3** Regex Explanation `(.*?(?:\)([,;])))`:

- `.*?`: any combination of characters (lazy - the least possible)
- `(?:\)([,;]))`: before a parenthesis followed by either a comma or colon

Then it's enough to replace your regex match with `($2, 1, NOW(), NOW())$4\n`

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q8DUsF/1).

Comment: can you share without the first digits column in another copy of this please

Comment: can you make another regex file same as ```('Afghanistan','AFG', 1, NOW(), NOW()),```

Comment: I only need results from regex, I don't want to another file

Comment: I want similar as you did above in regex101 but without the first digits like this: ```('Afghanistan','AFG', 1, NOW(), NOW()),```

Comment: I have updated the answer, does it help to you? @IhtishamKhan